# NSXMLParserDelegate not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to develop an XML parser in objective-C using the method described in http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser.

I have coded up the entire flow but the delegate call back methods just won't respond!

Please take a look at the following code blocks and let me know if you could figure out any mistakes/errors...

Parser is being called from:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cache" ofType:@"xml"];
NSLog(@"Path location is : %@",filePath);
NSData* xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlData];

if(nsXmlParser!=NULL)
{
     NSLog(@"parser is %@",nsXmlParser);
}

 HDDataXML *parser = [[HDDataXML alloc] initXMLParser];

[nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser];

BOOL success = [nsXmlParser parse];

// test the result
if (success)
{
    NSLog(@"No errors - effects count : i");
} else
{
    NSLog(@"Error parsing document!");
}
```

All I see here is *Error parsing document!* The *filePath* variable is OK and the parser is not null.

Now, in the delegate's .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
#import "EffectsCache.h"

@class EffectsCache;

@interface HDDataXML : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>
{

  EffectsCache *effectsHandler;
  NSMutableString *currentElementValue;
  NSMutableArray *effects;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string ;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
  didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;

 - (HDDataXML *) initXMLParser;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) EffectsCache *effectsHandler;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *effects;
  @end
```

And in the implementation of the delegate in .m:

```
 #import "HDDataXML.h"

@implementation HDDataXML
@synthesize effects, effectsHandler;

- (HDDataXML *) initXMLParser
{
    [super init];
    effects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"started parsing");

   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"effects"]) {
       NSLog(@"effects element found – create a new instance of EffectsCache class...");
       effectsHandler = [[EffectsCache alloc] init];

    }
}

  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
   {
      NSLog(@"mid parsing");
   if (!currentElementValue)
    {

       currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    }
else
{
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}

   NSLog(@"Processing value for : %@", string);
}

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

  NSLog(@"done parsing");

 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"effects"])
  {
       return;
   }

   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"effect"])
  {
     [effectsHandler addObject:effects];
     [effectsHandler release];
      effectsHandler = nil;
   }  
  else
   {
      NSLog(@"cuurent value - %@",currentElementValue);
     [effects setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
   }

   [currentElementValue release];
   currentElementValue = nil;
 }
```

Point is, the call back methods are not working.

Please help me find the bug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you declaring the NSXMLParser delegate methods to your .h file ?

Comment: Is this your actual code? In `[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlData]` you use a `NSData` object as a URL parameter. I would expect that that crashes immediately! - You probably meant `[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];`

Comment: No, it didn't crash on that line. But I did change it to initWithData:xmlData, but still not getting any result!

Comment: Do you get the `NSLog(@"parser is %@",nsXmlParser)` output?

Comment: yes, o/p is: parser is <NSXMLParser: 0x9dc6970>

Answer (score 0):

```
 nsXmlParser.delegate = self;
 [nsXmlParser parse];
```

and dont forget in the .h file to call the `delegate`

```
 <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that this answers the question. It is allowed to use a different object as delegate for the XML parser.

Comment: Isn't the same thing being done by : [nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser];

Comment: OK... I need the correct syntax for this: when I use interface HDDataXML:NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>, the program compiles and rund but nothing happens. when I use interface HDDataXML<NSXMLParserDelegate>:NSObject, the program doesn't compile. if I use interface HDDataXML<NSXMLParserDelegate>, the program compiles, runs and throws a funny warning:  *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x11b5b0 of class 'HDDataXML' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead and crashes. This is purely a syntax related problem (I guess). Somebody please explain !

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I solved it, finally:

As suggested by Martin R, I changed the code for calling the delegate:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"effects_cache" ofType:@"xml"];
NSLog(@"Path location is : %@",filePath);
NSData* xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
```

Before doing this modification, the *xmlData* was null.

One other small modification was needed:
change: 
      [effectsHandler addObject:effects];

TO

```
  [effects setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
```